# Console project fails with console.writeline but not console.readline

Tags: c#-4.0, sharpdevelop

I have a small sample program which breaks when it reaches line 50 with "Error CS1513: } expected". It's typical, except that I counted the number of curly brackets over and over and found no error.  I was told on [another forum](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/245147/cannot-put-member-fields-in-namespaces-but-they-arent.aspx) that the problem is probably my placement of the using keyword and class declarations, but I couldn't find anything wrong.

I would like to know if I'm making a mistake.  This is the entire program; written with SharpDevelop if it makes any difference.

```
using System;

namespace Problem
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassB MyObject = new ClassB();
            MyObject.MethodA();
        }
    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        public String str_a = "";
        public String str_b = "";
        public String str_c = "";
        public bool bool_a = false;
        public int[] int_a = new int[6];

        public void MethodA()
        {
            while (str_a == "" || str_a == null)
            {
                String str_a2 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (str_a2 == "" || str_a2 == null)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    str_a = str_a2;
                }
            }

            while (str_c == "")
            {
                String str_c2 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (str_c2 == "" || str_c2 == null)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    str_c = str_c2;
                }
            }

            while (bool_a == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(""); //Fails to compile, asks for ending brackets here

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 1)
                {
                    int_a[i] = 0;
                }
                bool_a = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this in visual studio because  I have tried this and it is working very fine.

Comment: No, but it was solved on that other forum I was talking about.  I posted the reason below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!  Classic error!  I had a declaration in a while loop:

```
while {
    public int[] int_b = new int[6];
}
```

Sorry about that, SO.  I was having one of those days...

Comment: what are you talking about there is no such a line in your code in the question!!!

Comment: Do a rollback and you will see it.  I took it out just before I thought about it potentially being the error.  I just didn't want to do the rollback because I already solved the error and there's no need to bump it up to the main page again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could be a victim of UNICODE quotes.

```
ʺ ̋“”″＂
```

Try just removing the double-quote characters and typing them **in your code editor**.

Comment: I tried that, but it wasn't the problem.  I had a different question with the answer being that I had Unicode quotes, so I made sure that I would check everything I could before asking.